# Problema para obtener el value del hidden que esta dentro de un datatable

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, datatable

Una Consulta, tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<thead>

  <th> Nombre y Apellido </th>
  <th> Curso </th>
  <th width="15%"> Division </th>     
  <th width="10%"> Ciclo Lectivo </th>      
    <th>  </th> 
    <th>  </th> 



      <tbody>
<?php foreach ($query as $registro): ?>
<tr>

  <td > <?= $registro->persona_name ?> </td>
  <td> <?= $registro->curso_anio ?> </td>
  <td> <?= $registro->curso_division ?> </td>
  <td width="15%"> <?= $registro->ciclolectivo?> </td>
  <td> <?= anchor('alumno/editCurso/'.$registro->id,'<i class="icon-pencil"></i>'); ?> </td>
  <th><input type="hidden" name="ver" value="<?= $registro->id?>">  </th>
```

```
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>nombre</th>
        <th>curso</th>
        <th>division</th>
        <th>ciclolectivo</th>


      </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

y este es mi codigo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var pos = oTable.row(this).index();
        var row = oTable.row(pos).data();
        console.log(row);



    } );

    $('#button').click( function () {
        var oData = oTable.rows('.selected').data();


        for (var i=0; i < oData.length ;i++){



            r=oData[i][5].value();
            alert(r);       

         }  

    } );
} );
```

¿Cómo puedo tomar solo el value del hidden que esta dentro de la tabla?

Gracias!!

Comment: Lo más práctico sería ponerle un `id` y luego recuperar el valor por ese id: `<input id="ibxHidden" type="hidden"  ...>` y luego `var elHidden=$('#ibxHidden').val();`  OJO, si tu elemento es este: `oData[i][5]` estás recuperando mal el valor, deberías hacerlo así: **`r=oData[i][5].val();`**

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas para recuperar ese valor, puedes obtenerlo así:

```
$('input:hidden').val()
```

o

```
$('input[name="ver"]').val()
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar de hacerlo como lo tienes planteado o puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Creamos un arreglo con los parámetros `title` y `class`:

```
$par = array('title' => $registro->id, 'class' => 'dato');
```

Creamos el `a` y agregamos los parametros:

```
<td><?= anchor('alumno/editCurso/'.$registro->id,'<i class="icon-pencil"></i>', $par); ?></td>
```

Obtienes el `title` del `enlace` al momento de que se ejecute el evento `click`:

```
$('.dato').click( function () {
    var id = this.title;
} );
```

o tambien:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.dato', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('title');
});
```

Listo, en la variable `id` ya tienes lo mismo que el `value` de tu `input` hidden sin necesidad de dicho `input`.

Otra de las alternativas que puedes hacer es simplemente obtener el `row` completo y acceder al dato de tu interés:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.dato', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = dt.row( tr );
    var id = row.data().id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo de esta manera.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   // se capturan todos los elementos de la fila
    var hidden = table.row(this);
    // se recorre cada elemento de la fila y se encuentra el valor del hidden
    $.each(hidden, (value)=>{
        console.log($(this).find(":hidden").val())
    })


} );
```

te dejo el ejemplo en JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AIf4/ugz8qLkp/14/ para ver el valor del hidden lo observas en la consola de google chrome.

Espero sea ayuda.